# How do I open apps by typing in the windows desktop, like in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system

In Linux, I noticed that when we are in the desktop environment, we can open an app by simply typing their name and pressing enter. Some kind of panel opens up when we start typing and we can see what app we are going to open.
In windows, we can do the same by pressing the windows key, then typing the name of our app. Is there a way to open an app in windows without pressing the windows key (and without using shortcuts)?

Comment: I don't think so, but if you want to you can use Windows-R and type in the name of the application

Comment: NO, Windows is Windows. Linux ISNOT Linux. It's a collection. If want to do so, install something onto your Windows.

Comment: Click the start button and start typing !?